# Shell script to change password every 90 days automatically

Tags: bash, shell

I am writing a shell script to change the password of OS users every 90 days.I will put the script in cron.Need help to increment the character in the password by 1.The password should change to sifs4you2 after 89 days.

```
#!/bin/bash
for i in `more userlist.txt `
do
echo $i
echo "sifs4you1" | passwd --stdin "$i"
echo;
#mailx -s "New Password for OS Users" <email> < /home/scripts/passwdsript.sh
```

done

Comment: `for i in \`more userlist.txt\`` is very poor - consider using a `while read ... done < userlist.txt`

Answer (score 0):

```
awk '{ match($0,/[[:digit:]]+$/);cnt=substr($0,RSTART,RLENGTH);print substr($0,1,RSTART-1)cnt+1}' <<< $i
```

With awk and $i containing the password to be incremented, we first match the password for 1 or more digits at the end of the password, reading the result into the variable cnt with the substr function. We then print out the rest of the password along with cnt incremented by 1 to form the new password.